# Flask HTML/AJAX page Linking Issue

Tags: python, html, flask

I have created a FLASK app which preforms CRUD operations on an SQL database. I had everything work a few days ago but now when using the web interface the HTML pages aren't working when clicked. For example after entering valid details and clicking login the URL now looks like:

[incorrect url path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lusFW.png)

when it should redirect to

[correct url path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgLaa.png)

showing in terminal
[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oHpT.png)

This is my folder layout
[folder layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmS6J.png)

My AJAX call to redirect to main.html
`

```
        // Login a user
        function userLogin() {
            data = getLogin()
            console.log(data)
            
            $.ajax({
                url:"http://127.0.0.1:5000/login",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                method:"POST",
                dataType:"JSON",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(result) {  

                    if (result == 1) {
                        window.location.replace("main.html");    // Redirect to to main.html if successful 
                    } 
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error){   
                    window.alert("Invaild username and/or password");
                    console.log("error "+ error + " code "+ status)
               }
            })
        }
```

`

Flask Server route:

`

```
# Homepage route
@app.route('/')
def index():
    if not 'username' in session:
        return app.send_static_file('index.html')


# Login 
@app.route("/login", methods = ["POST"])
def login():

    account = {
        "username":request.json["username"],
        "password":request.json["password"]       
    }

    return jsonify(bookmarkDAO.login(account))
```

`

I've tried deleting the cache, changing my folder directories around and I even tried an older version which correctly worked from my github repository but now it is even throwing the same error. I am using VS Code, could it possibly be an issue with the terminal?

Comment: I've figured it out after a whole day stuck  . AJAX url needs a "/" before the redirection otherwise the AJAX url will add on to the current url. It's always something so simple 

Answer (score 0):

You are not trailing the `main.html` with `/`

Change this

```
window.location.replace("main.html")
```

to

```
window.location.replace("/main.html")
```